# Multiple horizontal lines displayed between set of dynamically created tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing one issue while inserting horizontal line on the fly (i.e. at the time of creating dynamic tables).

As you can see from the code snippet below:

1) If you click on any row of the first table/grid, a horizontal line is shown below it and a new table is shown

2) If I click on any row of second grid/table ,everything looks good and a horizontal line is shown and a 3rd grid/table is shown

3) Click on 3rd grid , 4th grid is shown and a horizontal line. But when you click on 4th grid, you will notice an additional horizontal line getting added just above the grid as shown in the screenshot
(highlighted) below:

[image]

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

I am trying to accomplish this using an additional variable `hll` in the code. Not sure if it's redundant to use `hll` or I could use `hl` for the same purpose?

```
var hll = document.createElement('div');
  hll.id = 'newhorizLine';
  hll.style.margin = "25px 0";
  hll.style.height = "1px";
  hll.style.background = "black";
  hll.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), to(white), color-stop(50%, black))";
```

Please consider the code snippet below :

```js
var source = {
  localdata: [
    ["Test1", "2018-08-29 14:19:07", "2020-08-29 14:19:07", "Path1"],
    ["Test2", "2018-09-05 11:26:39", "2020-09-05 11:26:39", "Path2"],
    ["Test3", "2018-08-30 07:32:23", "2020-08-30 07:32:23", "Path3"],
    ["Test4", "2018-09-11 09:01:42", "2020-09-11 09:01:42", "Path4"],
    ["Test5", "2018-08-01 15:28:22", "2020-08-01 15:28:22", "Path5"],
    ["Test6", "2018-08-01 15:28:22", "2020-08-01 15:28:22", "Path6"],
    ["Test7", "2018-09-13 07:34:57", "2020-09-13 07:34:57", "Path7"]
  ],
  datafields: [{
      name: 'dataSetName',
      type: 'string',
      map: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'accessStartDate',
      type: 'date',
      map: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'accessEndDate',
      type: 'date',
      map: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'conceptPath',
      type: 'string',
      map: '3'
    }
  ],
  datatype: "array"
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
  loadComplete: function(data) {},
  loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});

$("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid({

  source: dataAdapter,
  width: 381,
  height: '200',
  pageable: true,
  sortable: true,
  autoheight: true,
  columnsResize: true,
  theme: 'classic',
  columns: [{
      text: 'Data Set',
      datafield: 'dataSetName',
      width: 140

    },
    {
      text: 'Start Date',
      datafield: 'accessStartDate',
      width: 120,
      cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy'
    },
    {
      text: 'End Date',
      datafield: 'accessEndDate',
      width: 120,
      cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy'
    },
    {
      text: 'Concept Path',
      datafield: 'conceptPath',
      width: 50,
      hidden: true
    }
  ]

});

// Row Select Logic Starts Here
$("#main_downloader_grid").on("rowselect", function(e) {
  let data_set_name = $("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'dataSetName');

  console.log("Cell Value Test");
  console.log(data_set_name.value);


  let conceptPath = $("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'conceptPath');
  console.log("Concept Path Test");
  console.log(conceptPath.value);


  $('#commonWindow').remove();
  //$('.clickable').remove();
  $('.clickable').next('#testbutton').remove();
    $('.clickable').slice(1).remove();


  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.id = 'commonWindow';
  //elem.setAttribute('style', 'margin:500px 10px 20px 20px;');


  console.log(elem);



  let data = [{
      letter: '<b>People</b>'
    },
    {
      letter: '1) Detailed demographics data of all people'
    },
    {
      letter: '2) Attributes associated with all people'
    },
    {
      letter: '<b>Technology</b>'
    },
    {
      letter: '1) Computer details'
    },
    {
      letter: '2) Hardware Details'
    },
    {
      letter: '3) Software Details'
    },
    {
      letter: '<b>Company Details</b>'
    }
    /* {conceptpath: conceptPath.value } */
  ];
  let source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array",
    datafields: [{
      name: 'letter',
      type: 'string'
    } /* ,{ name: 'conceptpath', type: 'string' } */ ]
  };
  let newDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

  $(elem).jqxGrid({
    source: newDataAdapter,
    width: 395,
    height:310,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Data set <b>' + data_set_name.value + '</b> selected, what data do you want to see?',
        datafield: 'letter'
        //width: 450
      }

    ]
  });
 
 $(elem).insertAfter('#main_downloader_grid');
  elem.style.margin = "50px 10px 20px 50px";
  
  var hl = document.createElement('div');
  hl.id = 'horizLine';
  hl.style.margin = "25px 0";
  hl.style.height = "1px";
  hl.style.background = "black";
  hl.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), to(white), color-stop(50%, black))";
  $(hl).insertAfter('#main_downloader_grid');
  
  
  var hll = document.createElement('div');
  hll.id = 'newhorizLine';
  hll.style.margin = "25px 0";
  hll.style.height = "1px";
  hll.style.background = "black";
  hll.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), to(white), color-stop(50%, black))";
  
  

$("#commonWindow").on("rowselect", handleClick);



function handleClick(e) {
  var $el = $("<div />", {
    class: "clickable",
    style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 20px ",
  })
  .on('click', handleClick)

  $el.jqxGrid({
    height: 270,width:520, pageable: true,source: dataAdapter, columns: [
      { text: 'Data Set Name', datafield: 'dataSetName', width: 200 },
      { text: 'Access Start Date', datafield: 'accessStartDate', width: 150,cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy' },
      { text: 'Access End Date', datafield: 'accessEndDate', width: 150,cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy' },
      { text: 'Concept Path', datafield: 'conceptPath', width: 100,hidden:true }
     
    ]
  });
  
 $(hll).insertAfter(".clickable");

  var $this = $(this), $parent = $(this).parent();

  if (e.type == 'rowselect') {
     $('.clickable').next('#testbutton').remove();
     $('.clickable').next('#newhorizline').remove();
     $('.clickable').slice(1).remove();
  }

  var $button = $("<div id = 'testbutton'></div>").on('click', function (e) {
       $(".clickable").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'csv', 'jqxGrid');
  });
  
 
  console.log($button);

  
  $button.jqxButton({ width: 100, height: 20});
    $button.html('Download Data');

  $el.after($button);

    $parent.append($el);
  $(this).off('click');
}


});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="main_downloader_grid" style="margin:50px 10px 20px 50px"></div>
  <div class="clickable" style="margin:50px 10px 20px 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While, I am not exactly sure what you are try to accomplish, you can get horizontal lines without css using the

---

tag in html!

```html
<h2>Hello!</h2>
<hr>
<h3>Hi, Tim!</h3>
```

Comment: Basically, I am trying to add horizontal line below each table as soon as it's created. I mean, if I click first table, new table is created below it, so first table will have horizontal line below it. Similarly, second table will have line below it when third is created etc